# Rebuilding the recycler view causes it to disappear

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

In my code, I am building a recycler view, via the method`setUpRecyclerView(country);`, when my fragment is fast created and later on I call the same method (or various other methods that build a recycler view e.g.`setUpRecyclerViewWithKeyword(country, search_key);` , `setUpRecyclerViewWithPreferences(country, anime, art, edu, gaming, music, other);` ,  `setUpRecyclerViewWithKeywordAndPreferences(country, search_key, anime, art, edu, gaming, music, other);` ) to build the recyler view again. This is illustrated below:

**My Fragments OnViewCreated code**

```
  public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        final String id = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        search_keyword = getView().findViewById(R.id.exp_search);
        search_btn = getView().findViewById(R.id.exp_search_btn);
        ccp = getView().findViewById(R.id.exp_ccp);
        refresh = getView().findViewById(R.id.refresh);
        country = ccp.getSelectedCountryName();
        setUpRecyclerView(country);
        Log.e("explore frag","1");
        db.collection("Users").document(id).collection("preferences").document("event").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = task.getResult();
                    if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                        String anime = documentSnapshot.get("anime").toString();
                        String art = documentSnapshot.get("art").toString();
                        String edu = documentSnapshot.get("edu").toString();
                        String gaming = documentSnapshot.get("gaming").toString();
                        String music = documentSnapshot.get("music").toString();
                        String other = documentSnapshot.get("other").toString();
                        String all = documentSnapshot.get("all").toString();
                        String search_key = search_keyword.getText().toString().trim();
                        country = ccp.getSelectedCountryName();
                        if (all.equals("1") && TextUtils.isEmpty(search_key)) {
                            setUpRecyclerView(country);
                            Log.e("explore frag","2");
                        } else if (all.equals("1") && !(TextUtils.isEmpty(search_key))) {
                            setUpRecyclerViewWithKeyword(country, search_key);
                            Log.e("explore frag","3");
                        } else if (all.equals("0") && TextUtils.isEmpty(search_key)) {
                            setUpRecyclerViewWithPreferences(country, anime, art, edu, gaming, music, other);
                            Log.e("explore frag","4");
                        } else {
                            setUpRecyclerViewWithKeywordAndPreferences(country, search_key, anime, art, edu, gaming, music, other);
                            Log.e("explore frag","5");
                        }


                    }

                }

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

            }
        });
        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(
                new ExplorePageAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void OnItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position) {

                        String id = documentSnapshot.getId();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                                event_customer_view_activity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("Event_ID", id);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        //   getActivity().finish();

                    }
                }
        );

    }
```

**RecylerView building method**

```
   private void setUpRecyclerView(String country) {

        Log.e("explore frag",country);
        Query query = Cref.whereEqualTo("country", country);
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<POJO_explore_page_item> options = new
                FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<POJO_explore_page_item>()
                .setQuery(query, POJO_explore_page_item.class).
                        build();

        adapter = new ExplorePageAdapter(options);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = getView().findViewById(R.id.explore_recycler);
//        recyclerView.setAdapter(null);
//        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(null);
//        recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().clear();
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
```

My problem is that whenever I try to rebuild the new recycler view, there is no result unllke the first time the recyler view is built. It is almost as though the recycler view disappeares.

**Attempted solutions:**

I have tried adding `recyclerView.setAdapter(null);` and`recyclerView.setLayoutManager(null);`  before

```
  recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I have also tried rebuilding the recyler view in my OnViewCreated method

```
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        final String id = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        search_keyword = getView().findViewById(R.id.exp_search);
        search_btn = getView().findViewById(R.id.exp_search_btn);
        ccp = getView().findViewById(R.id.exp_ccp);
        refresh = getView().findViewById(R.id.refresh);
        country = ccp.getSelectedCountryName();
        //setUpRecyclerView(country);

        ///
        Log.e("explore frag",country);
        Query query = Cref.whereEqualTo("country", country);
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<POJO_explore_page_item> options = new
                FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<POJO_explore_page_item>()
                .setQuery(query, POJO_explore_page_item.class).
                        build();

        adapter = new ExplorePageAdapter(options);
       final RecyclerView recyclerView = getView().findViewById(R.id.explore_recycler);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        ///
        Log.e("explore frag","1");
        db.collection("Users").document(id).collection("preferences").document("event").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = task.getResult();
                    if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                        String anime = documentSnapshot.get("anime").toString();
                        String art = documentSnapshot.get("art").toString();
                        String edu = documentSnapshot.get("edu").toString();
                        String gaming = documentSnapshot.get("gaming").toString();
                        String music = documentSnapshot.get("music").toString();
                        String other = documentSnapshot.get("other").toString();
                        String all = documentSnapshot.get("all").toString();
                        String search_key = search_keyword.getText().toString().trim();
                        country = ccp.getSelectedCountryName();
                        if (all.equals("1") && TextUtils.isEmpty(search_key)) {
                          //  setUpRecyclerView(country);

                            Query query = Cref.whereEqualTo("country", country);
                            FirestoreRecyclerOptions<POJO_explore_page_item> options = new
                                    FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<POJO_explore_page_item>()
                                    .setQuery(query, POJO_explore_page_item.class).
                                            build();

                            adapter = new ExplorePageAdapter(options);

                            recyclerView.setAdapter(null);
                            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(null);
                            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                            Log.e("explore frag","2");
                        } else if (all.equals("1") && !(TextUtils.isEmpty(search_key))) {
                            setUpRecyclerViewWithKeyword(country, search_key);
                            Log.e("explore frag","3");
                        } else if (all.equals("0") && TextUtils.isEmpty(search_key)) {
                            setUpRecyclerViewWithPreferences(country, anime, art, edu, gaming, music, other);
                            Log.e("explore frag","4");
                        } else {
                            setUpRecyclerViewWithKeywordAndPreferences(country, search_key, anime, art, edu, gaming, music, other);
                            Log.e("explore frag","5");
                        }


                    }

                }

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

            }
        });
       adapter.setOnItemClickListener(
                new ExplorePageAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void OnItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position) {

                        String id = documentSnapshot.getId();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                                event_customer_view_activity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("Event_ID", id);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        //   getActivity().finish();

                    }
                }
        );

    }
```

Neither of these two attempts worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: When using a recyclerview and an adapter you should only ever set the adapter once. After that if your content has changed set the changed list of items in the adapter and then call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() and your recyclerview will show the list of the updated content.

Comment: @just_user Is this also the case for FirebaseUI Firestore recycler views as I have used in my original post? If so, can you give me an example?

Comment: Sorry, no. Its not exactly the case the case for FirestoreRecyclerAdapter. In this one there are built in snapshot listeners which calls notifyDataSetChanged when changes are received from Firebase. So this should be done automatically. I have never used FirestoreRecyclerAdapter myself, but the key is the adapter. But in general when you start the adapter.startListening() in your activity the adapter should handle it self and update the list automatically. If you need to change the content to another list, stop the listener, create a new adapter and then start listening again.

Comment: Found this tutorial: https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/firebaseui-firestorerecycleradapter/part-3-firestorerecycleradapter. And from firebase experience, don't try to force an update locally if you for instance add something to the list. Att it to firestore and wait for the update to arrive to your list.

Comment: @just_user Your second comment has helped. I posted a representaion of my solution as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

As @just_user's second comment on my original post implies, I have to call `adapter.stopListening()` before I create a new adapter. Afterwards, I can call `adapter.startListening()`.This is illustrated below:

```
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        final String id = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        search_keyword = getView().findViewById(R.id.exp_search);
        search_btn = getView().findViewById(R.id.exp_search_btn);
        ccp = getView().findViewById(R.id.exp_ccp);
        refresh = getView().findViewById(R.id.refresh);
        country = ccp.getSelectedCountryName();
        setUpRecyclerViewInitial(country);
        db.collection("Users").document(id).collection("preferences").document("event").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = task.getResult();
                    if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                        String anime = documentSnapshot.get("anime").toString();
                        String art = documentSnapshot.get("art").toString();
                        String edu = documentSnapshot.get("edu").toString();
                        String gaming = documentSnapshot.get("gaming").toString();
                        String music = documentSnapshot.get("music").toString();
                        String other = documentSnapshot.get("other").toString();
                        String all = documentSnapshot.get("all").toString();
                        String search_key = search_keyword.getText().toString().trim();
                        country = ccp.getSelectedCountryName();
                        adapter.stopListening();
                            RebuildRecyclerView(country);

                    }

                }

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

            }
        });
      
        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(
                new ExplorePageAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void OnItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position) {

                        String id = documentSnapshot.getId();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                                event_customer_view_activity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("Event_ID", id);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        //   getActivity().finish();

                    }
                }
        );


    }

    private void setUpRecyclerViewInitial(String country) {
//.whereIn("type", Arrays.asList("Other"))
        Log.e("explore frag",country);
        Query query = Cref.whereEqualTo("country", country).orderBy("count", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<POJO_explore_page_item> options = new
                FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<POJO_explore_page_item>()
                .setQuery(query, POJO_explore_page_item.class).
                        build();

        adapter = new ExplorePageAdapter(options);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = getView().findViewById(R.id.explore_recycler);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

   private void RebuildRecyclerView(String country) {
//.whereIn("type", Arrays.asList("Other"))
        Log.e("explore frag",country);
        Query query = Cref.whereEqualTo("country", country).orderBy("count", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<POJO_explore_page_item> options = new
                FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<POJO_explore_page_item>()
                .setQuery(query, POJO_explore_page_item.class).
                        build();

        adapter = new ExplorePageAdapter(options);
adapter.startListening()
        RecyclerView recyclerView = getView().findViewById(R.id.explore_recycler);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();

    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        adapter.startListening();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        adapter.stopListening();

    }
```